# Recommendations for a "Fiber Inspection Scope" to use on SC, LC and MTP connections

Tags: networking

I'm looking for recommendations for a "Fiber Inspection Scope" to use on SC, LC and MTP connections.

My environment:

- Small Datacenter.
- will have to inspect and trouble shoot about 10
  fiber optic links per week.
- connection types: SC, LC and MTP.
- cable types: multi mode and single mode.
- Generalist Skill level
- Budget $100 - $500 USD

Comment: What exactly is a fiber inspections scope? What's it do, how's it work?

Comment: @ArtOfCode  An inspection scope is basically using a strand of fibre optic cable, and mounting a tiny USB camera to one end, and coating in a protective layer.  http://www.flukenetworks.com/datacom-cabling/fiber-testing/fiberinspector-mini    A fiber version is one simple designed to look at the end of a piece of fiber and allow the user to check for defects.  Also to poke into a tiny hole in a wall and see what is going on behind the scenes.